# Can a drupal admin user get FTP rights to a godaddy server

Tags: 7, files

I have a Drupal 7.28 site running on a godaddy server.  I just recently copied it from my local box to godaddy's.  I can't use the function "add module by using URL" method now.  I see the message that I must have FTP rights.  I do have FTP rights when logged in to godaddy through their interface, but wondering if a drupal admin user can be given FTP rights and then be able to add modules, etc through URL's at the "Add module" page?  How does everyone deal with this?  Do you just manually FTP modules to the server and then go back to drupal's interface and enable?  Or do you use Drush to install modules remotely?  Just wondering how everyone deals with this...  Is it best practice to not make a site live until all modules are installed locally and then move the site to a remote server?

Thanks for the help.

Dave N

Comment: if you don't have shell access than you cannot use Drush. and your question title seems to be misleading. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Drush. But using the install module function at admin/modules/install I have installed modules before when live on a GoDaddy server.

I don't know what is causing the problem, I would maybe contact their support. But certainly it's doable, and I've done it in the past.

However depending on the module I would stay clear of installing on a live server, particularly if you are on shared hosting environment with GoDaddy (contrary to a lot of people I actually find them okay and the best solution at that price for hosting a site).

However whilst you'll find installing modules okay you may find you run into problems enabling them with PHP memory limits, or other server issues. Generally doing dev on a local machine if you have hosting like GoDaddy is going to be faster, more flexible, and generally easier.

Comment: Thank you.  So on your instance of using godaddy, when you do actually add modules directly to it, if you ever do remotely, do you use "add module by URL" or do you download the module, ftp it to your site and then install/enable?  The only thing I can't do now is install using the URL remotely.

Comment: I just did a test just now myself, and installed the Boost module on my live GoDaddy shared hosting account. Installed fine with no problems.

Comment: For clarification, that installation was using the installing via URL method.